# Python/SQLAlchemy calling Stored Procedure(Postgres) with parameter

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, parameters, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with this code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

con_str = 'postgresql://user:password@IP_PostgresDB:5432/base'

app = Flask(__name__)

#Acesso a base
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = con_str
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

conn = db.engine.raw_connection()

results = conn.cursor().callproc("usp_pes_pessoa",[1])

#...
```

My reference was:

[1]https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures

When following the sample code, the procedure is not invoked

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The problem is you didn't read the `psycopg2` docs. See [callproc](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=callproc#cursor.callproc), in particular the **Note:**. The issue being the SQLAlchemy docs are not entirely correct, because they imply that a stored function == stored procedure and that is not the case.

Comment: Hi @Adrian - If there is an error in the SQLAlchemy docs we'd greatly appreciate it if you could open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues) (or even submit a PR!) so we can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver. I wasted all my sunday trying to make it work. I really appreciate if you have a code or reference where I can know how I can import to Pycharm(Python 3.9 )  and open a connection using PYSCOPG2. Thanks for your time

Comment: Again, if you had taken the time to read the underlying documentation you would have gotten to solution hours ago. This has been pointed out to you before. As to PyCharm, I don't use it so there is not much I can help with there. I would suggest opening a separate question for that with a detailed description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver I will do it.

Comment: @GordThompson, see issue [7051](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7051)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I saw your point about to use execute(), but how can I receive OUT parameter? Have any way using execute()? Thx

Comment: Like you would anything returned from an `execute()`, use one the `fetch*()` functions. Though unless you are using Postgres 14+ a stored procedure does not have `OUT`  but `INOUT`.